# Array conversion from one style to other

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

how can i change this array

```
<pre>
Array ( [0] => 68,Off 
        [1] => 07,Do 
        [2] => 88,Ph 
        [3] => )
</pre>
```

To this one

```
<pre>
Array ( [68] => Off 
        [07] => Do 
        [88] => Ph 
        [3] => )
</pre>
```

Please help....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this one

```
$temp=array();
foreach($arr as $each)
{
     $val=explode(",",$each);
     $temp[$val[0]]=$val[1];
}
echo "<pre>";print_r($temp);
```

please let me know if you face any problem.

Comment: That is Perfect solution to me.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
<?php
    $array_1=your_array_here;
    $array_2=array();
    foreach($array_1 as $value){
      $parts=explode(',',$value);
      $array_2[$parts[0]]=$parts[1];
    }
    print_r($array_2);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$finalArray = array();
 foreach($arr as $row)
 {
   $newArr = explode(',',$row); 
    $finalArray[$newArr[0]] = $newArr[1]; 
 }
 print_r($finalArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

The clearest and easiest way would be to create a new array and loop through the old one:

```
$new_array = array();
foreach ($old_array as $val) {
    $val = explode(',', $val);
    $new_array [$val[0]] = $val[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
   $array = array('68,Off', '07,Do', '88,Ph'); // Old array
   $tidy = array(); // New array

   for( $i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++ ){
        $tmp = explode(",", $array[$i]);
        $tidy[$tmp[0]] = $tmp[1];
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to accomplish what you want. Here's one of them. This solution will preserve the original key if there are no commas in the value.

```
<?php
$new_array = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    list($new_key, $new_value) = explode(",", $value);
    if (!strstr($value, ",")) {
        list($new_key, $new_value) = array($key, $value);
    }
    $new_array[$new_key] = $new_value;
}
print_r($new_array);
?>
```